# Running fsck from cygwin shell?

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, fsck, ext2

I need to be able to check / fix file system errors on SD cards from a win7 box. I had hoped to use e2fsck from cygwin but am having some issues getting this to work. (SD cards are used to boot fanless PCs to debian)

SD cards in question have 3 partitions - 2 of which are ext2. When I plug the card into the win7 machine I only see /dev/sdb1 appear. (unf dmesg isn't installed so i can't see what errors might be).

When I try e2fsck on this partition Im told "bad magic number in superblock", etc etc. This leads me to believe it isn't a linux partition.

(Note - if I put this SD card in a CentOS machine I see all three partitions appear and can work with them)

Anyway: question(s):

- is there a better way to check / fix ext2 partitions from a win7 machine?
- is there a way to get e2fsck to work from cygwin?

Comment: WSL2 can run e2fsck and is WAY WAY better than CYGWIN.

Answer (score 0):

Due to limitations of the cygwin environment I would recommend using a virtual machine (that's what I have done in the past).  Set up the Linux environment you are accustomed to using (with or without X) using Virtual Box or some alternative and then bridge access to your SD Card adapter.  Under VirtualBox you can enable access under the VM settings -> USB -> Enable USB Controller and add the appropriate filter for your SD card adapter.  You should then be able to access the sdcard as your expected block device file(s) under /dev and run fsck.